# Call a function from static method

Tags: react-native

I have something like this:

```
    const BasketButton2 = ({ isWhite, style, navigation }) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={[styles.button, style]}
                onPress={() => Header.addInstaPost()}
            >
                <Icon
                    family="Entypo"
                    size={16}
                    name="new-message"
                    color={theme.COLORS[isWhite ? 'WHITE' : 'ICON']}
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
        
        class Header extends React.Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.state = {
                notifications: false,
                loading: true,
                error: null,
                modalVisible: false,
                modalThanksVisible: false,
                reportSubmitted: false,
                reportError: false,
            };
        }
    handleLeftPress = () => {
            const { back, navigation } = this.props;
            return back ? navigation.goBack() : navigation.openDrawer();
        };    
    renderRight = () => {
        const { white, title, navigation, scene } = this.props;
    
        if (global.loggedUser === true) {
            return [
                <BasketButton2
                    key="basket-search"
                    navigation={navigation}
                    isWhite={white}
                />,
                <ChatButton
                    key="chat-search"
                    navigation={navigation}
                    isWhite={white}
                />,
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                <BasketButton
                    key="basket-search"
                    navigation={navigation}
                    isWhite={white}
                />,
                <ChatButton
                    key="chat-search"
                    navigation={navigation}
                    isWhite={white}
                />,
            ];
        } 
    };
renderSearch = () => {
        const { navigation } = this.props;
        return (
            <Input
                right
                color="black"
                style={styles.search}
                placeholder="What are you looking for?"
                onFocus={() => navigation.navigate('Search')}
                iconContent={
                    <Icon
                        size={16}
                        color={theme.COLORS.MUTED}
                        name="magnifying-glass"
                        family="entypo"
                    />
                }
            />
        );
    };

    renderOptions = () => {
        const { navigation, optionLeft, optionRight } = this.props;
        return (
            <Block row style={styles.tabs}>
                <Button
                    shadowless
                    style={[styles.tab, styles.divider]}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Categories')}
                >
                    <Block row middle>
                        <Icon name="globe" family="feather" style={{ paddingRight: 8 }} />
                        <Text size={16} style={styles.tabTitle}>
                            {optionLeft || 'Locations'}
                        </Text>
                    </Block>
                </Button>
                <Button
                    shadowless
                    style={styles.tab}
                    onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Deals')}
                >
                    <Block row middle>
                        <Icon name="grid" family="feather" style={{ paddingRight: 8 }} />
                        <Text size={16} style={styles.tabTitle}>
                            {optionRight || 'Categories'}
                        </Text>
                    </Block>
                </Button>
            </Block>
        );
    };

    renderTabs = () => {
        const { tabs, tabIndex, navigation } = this.props;
        const defaultTab = tabs && tabs[0] && tabs[0].id;

        if (!tabs) return null;

        return (
            <Tabs
                data={tabs || []}
                initialIndex={tabIndex || defaultTab}
                onChange={(id) => navigation.setParams({ tabId: id })}
            />
        );
    };

    renderHeader = () => {
        const { search, tabs, options } = this.props;
        if (search || tabs || options) {
            return (
                <Block center>
                    {search ? this.renderSearch() : null}
                    {options ? this.renderOptions() : null}
                    {tabs ? this.renderTabs() : null}
                </Block>
            );
        }
        return null;
    };
    
    
    addInstaPost = () => {
                this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
            };
render() {
        const { back, title, white, transparent, navigation, scene } = this.props;

        const noShadow = ['Profile'].includes(title);
        const noShadowWhite = ['Search'].includes(title);
        const headerStyles = [
            !noShadow ? styles.shadow : null,
            transparent ? { backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' } : null,
        ];

        var myHeaderStyle = styles.shadow;
        if (noShadow) {
            var myHeaderStyle = '';
        } else if (transparent) {
            var myHeaderStyle = "{ backgroundColor: 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' }";
        } else if (noShadowWhite) {
            var myHeaderStyle = styles.searchShadow;
        }

        return (
            <Block style={myHeaderStyle}>
                <View style={styles.imageContainer} transparent={transparent}>
                    {
                        this.renderInstaPostButton()
                    }
                </View>

                <View style={styles.item}>
                    <NavBar
                        back={back}
                        title={title}
                        style={styles.navbar}
                        transparent={transparent}
                        right={this.renderRight()}
                        rightStyle={{ alignItems: 'center' }}
                        leftStyle={{ paddingTop: 3, flex: 0.3 }}
                        leftIconName={back ? 'leftcircle' : 'menu-fold'}
                        leftIconFamily="AntDesign"
                        leftIconSize="1.6"
                        leftIconColor={
                            white ? materialTheme.COLORS.NAVICON : theme.COLORS.ICON
                        }
                        titleStyle={[
                            styles.title,
                            { color: theme.COLORS[white ? 'WHITE' : 'ICON'] },
                        ]}
                        onLeftPress={this.handleLeftPress}
                    />
                </View>
                {this.renderHeader()}
            </Block>
        );
    }
}
```

So basically inside BasketButton2 I am trying to make a call to a function which is inside the class Header.

onPress={() => Header.addInstaPost() is not working

as well as onPress={() => this.addInstaPost()

I am getting Header.addInstaPost is not defined.

How I can refer to function inside class?

Thanks!!

Comment: How are Header and BasketButton2 related?

Comment: I added to original post right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `addInstaPost` as a property to `BasketButton2`

```
class Header extends React.Component {
    addInstaPost = () => {
        this.setState({ modalVisible: true });
    };

    renderRight = () => {
        const { white, title, navigation, scene } = this.props;
    
        if (global.loggedUser === true) {
            return [
                <BasketButton2
                    key="basket-search"
                    navigation={navigation}
                    isWhite={white}
                    onPress={this.addInstaPost}
                />,
                <ChatButton
                    key="chat-search"
                    navigation={navigation}
                    isWhite={white}
                />,
            ];
        } else {
            return [
                <BasketButton
                    key="basket-search"
                    navigation={navigation}
                    isWhite={white}
                />,
                <ChatButton
                    key="chat-search"
                    navigation={navigation}
                    isWhite={white}
                />,
            ];
        } 
    };
}
```

```
const BasketButton2 = ({ isWhite, style, navigation, onPress }) => (
    <TouchableOpacity
        style={[styles.button, style]}
        onPress={onPress}
    >
        <Icon
            family="Entypo"
            size={16}
            name="new-message"
            color={theme.COLORS[isWhite ? 'WHITE' : 'ICON']}
        />
    </TouchableOpacity>
);
```

IMO this is the most prefered way for such case